# Is there any way to create EF mapping classes using Visual Studio or other tools from a SQLite Database?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core

Here is one that I created for a SQL Server a while ago.  But I need similar for a new SQLite Database now.

```
    public TopicMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.TopicId);

        // Identity
        this.Property(t => t.TopicId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        this.Property(t => t.Number)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.Version)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(8)
            .IsRowVersion();

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Topic");
        this.Property(t => t.TopicId).HasColumnName("TopicId");
        this.Property(t => t.Number).HasColumnName("Number");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        this.Property(t => t.SubjectId).HasColumnName("SubjectId");
        this.Property(t => t.Version).HasColumnName("Version");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("CreatedBy");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedDate).HasColumnName("CreatedDate");
        this.Property(t => t.ModifiedBy).HasColumnName("ModifiedBy");
        this.Property(t => t.ModifiedDate).HasColumnName("ModifiedDate");
        this.Property(t => t.Created).HasColumnName("Created");
        this.Property(t => t.Modified).HasColumnName("Modified");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Subject)
            .WithMany(t => t.Topics)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.SubjectId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
```

I now have a complex SQLite Database but cannot find any tools at all that will work to create the model and mapping classes automatically.

Does anyone know of anything that exists?

Answer (score 1):

With EF Core, you can use EF Core Power Tools. You must install the SQLite Visual Studio Tools.

More info here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I installed the tools.  However does that also give me the properties such as this.Property(t => t.Version)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(8)
            .IsRowVersion(); and the relationships?

Comment: Yes, it does (for all the non-default ones)